# Why does my Team Foundation Build run fewer Nunit tests than Resharper?

Tags: nunit, tfsbuild

We have a TFS build definition configured to run NUnit tests as follows:

[image]

This works fine, and the build controller runs the tests.  Here's the build outcome in TFS 2017's web portal:

[image]

However!  Only 1802 tests get run, but Resharper will detect 2039 tests:

[image]

We noticed that some test fixtures were missing the `[TestFixture]` attribute, and some tests missing `[Test]`, but this doesn't seem to have helped.

Can anyone help me work out which tests aren't being run by our CI build, and also why they're not being run?

Comment: What is the name of the dll with the tests that do not run? They need to have the name * test *.dll (worth a check).

Comment: I don't know which tests aren't running, that's the point. All my test assemblies have "test" in the name.

Comment: Without being able to see your test assemblies, this is pretty difficult to answer! I would download the nunit3-console exe and pass all you test assemblies into that, to see which value is the correct one. Once you know which runner is wrong, you can maybe start looking into why. Resharper sometimes incorrectly duplicates tests, it's NUnit runner has had problems before.

Comment: +1 to Chris' suggestion. Also, NUnit has no requirements regarding the name of a test assembly. You would only need to have "test" in the name if you were selecting them using a wildcard, externally to NUnit.